# Powershell ODBC Get Schema Metadata

Tags: database, powershell, odbc

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the schema data of an ODBC connection using Powershell?  I'm working with an old DBMS and there is nothing like "Information_Schema".  I want to be able to get a list of tables with all their associated columns, data types, etc.

Comment: There is a PowerShell command introduced in v4.0 named Get-OdbcDsn that can get you the Data Source Names. I'm not familiar with what Information_Schema is but maybe give it a shot if you haven't already. Maybe there is some data in there that might get you closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to adjust the connection string and object structure to fit your specific DSN, but here's the gist of it.

```
function Get-ODBCSchema{
   param(
      [string]
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
      $DataSourceName
   )
   try{$dsn = get-odbcdsn $DataSourceName -ErrorAction Stop}catch {
      throw $_.Exception
   }
   if($dsn.Platform -NotMatch ([IntPtr]::Size*8))
      {throw "You're currently in $([IntPtr]::Size*8)-Bit PowerShell, and the ODBC is only available in $($dsn.Platform)"}
   
   $con = [System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection]::new()
   $con.ConnectionString = 'DSN={0}' -f $DataSourceName
   $con.open()
   write-host "Downloading Column Data from $DataSourceName, this may take some time"
   $columns = $con.GetSchema('Columns')
   write-host 'got it'
   $con.close();$con.dispose()
   $count = $columns.Rows.Count
   [int]$aPercent = $count / 100
   
   $ret = @{}; $i = $j = 0
   $columns.Rows.GetEnumerator().foreach{
      $qual  = $_.TABLE_QUALIFIER.ToString()
      $owner = $_.TABLE_OWNER.ToString()
      $tName = $_.TABLE_NAME.ToString()
      $cName = $_.COLUMN_NAME.ToString()
      
      if($ret.Keys -NotContains $qual)
         {$ret.$qual = @{$owner = @{$tName = @{$cName = $_}}}}
      elseif($ret.$qual.Keys -NotContains $owner)
         {$ret.$qual.$owner = @{$tName = @{$cName = $_}}}
      elseif($ret.$qual.$owner.Keys -NotContains $tName)
         {$ret.$qual.$owner.$tName = @{$cName = $_}}
      else
         {$ret.$qual.$owner.$tName.$cName = $_}
      if(!($i++ % $aPercent)){
         write-progress -Activity 'Building Schema Table' -Status ('Added Column: {0:#,##0} of {1:#,##0}' -f $i,$count) -PercentComplete ($j++)
      }
   }
   write-progress -Activity 'Building Schema Table' -Completed
   if($ret.Keys.Count -eq 1 -And $ret.Keys[0].Length -eq 0)
      {$ret = $ret.Values[0]}
   return $ret
}
```

---

### Edit1: Figuring out what needs to be fine-tuned

Open up PowerShell

```
PS C:\working> 'This PowerShell session is running in {0}-bit mode' -f ([IntPtr]::Size*8)
This PowerShell session is running in 64-bit mode
PS C:\working> Get-OdbcDsn 'Excel Files'
Name       : Excel Files
DsnType    : User
Platform   : 32-bit
DriverName : Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
Attribute  : {SafeTransactions, DriverId, ImplicitCommitSync, Threads...}
```

Dang, the DSN platform only works in 32-bit mode but this PS is on 64-bit. So I guess we'll need to launch a new 32-bit session

```
PS C:\working> start-process $env:SystemRoot\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

ok now we should be good to start digging

```
PS C:\working> 'This PowerShell session is running in {0}-bit mode' -f ([IntPtr]::Size*8)
This PowerShell session is running in 32-bit mode
PS C:\working> $con = [System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection]::new()
PS C:\working> $con.ConnectionString = 'DSN=Excel Files'
PS C:\working> $con.Open()
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
SQLSetConnectAttr failed"
At line:1 char:1
+ $con.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OdbcException
```

ok, maybe it needs a file name?

```
PS C:\working> $con.ConnectionString = 'DSN=Excel Files;File Name={0}' -f (ls '.\Book1.xlsx').FullName
PS C:\working> $con.Open()
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
SQLSetConnectAttr failed
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute File Name
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute File Name
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute File Name
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute File Name
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute File Name
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute File Name
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute File Name
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute File Name"
At line:1 char:1
+ $con.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OdbcException
```

different error, hopefully moving in the right direction now it's complaining about `attribute File Name`

```
PS C:\working> $con.ConnectionString = 'DSN=Excel Files;Data Source={0}' -f (ls '.\Book1.xlsx').FullName
PS C:\working> $con.Open()
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
SQLSetConnectAttr failed
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute Data Source
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute Data Source
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute Data Source
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute Data Source
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute Data Source
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute Data Source
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute Data Source
ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver]Invalid connection string attribute Data Source"
At line:1 char:1
+ $con.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OdbcException
```

so much for dumb luck; apparently it's not `attribute Data Source` either. Maybe I should go find out what [Excel's magic words are](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)? Looks like it might be `Dbq`; because well... Excel?

```
PS C:\working> $con.ConnectionString = 'DSN=Excel Files;Dbq={0}' -f (ls '.\Book1.xlsx').FullName
PS C:\working> $con.Open()
PS C:\working>
```

and just like that we've got our foot the door; so let's see what we can find.

```
PS C:\working> $con.GetSchema()

CollectionName        NumberOfRestrictions NumberOfIdentifierParts
--------------        -------------------- -----------------------
MetaDataCollections                      0                       0
DataSourceInformation                    0                       0
DataTypes                                0                       0
Restrictions                             0                       0
ReservedWords                            0                       0
Columns                                  4                       4
Indexes                                  4                       4
Tables                                   3                       3
Views                                    3                       3


PS C:\working> $tableinfo = $con.GetSchema('Tables')
PS C:\working> $enu = $tableinfo.Rows.GetEnumerator()
PS C:\working> $enu.MoveNext()
True
PS C:\working> $enu.Current


TABLE_CAT   : C:\working\Book1.xlsx
TABLE_SCHEM :
TABLE_NAME  : Sheet1$
TABLE_TYPE  : SYSTEM TABLE
REMARKS     :



PS C:\working> $columninfo = $con.GetSchema('Columns')
PS C:\working> $enu = $columninfo.Rows.GetEnumerator()
PS C:\working> $enu.MoveNext();$enu.Current
True


TABLE_CAT         : C:\working\Book1.xlsx
TABLE_SCHEM       :
TABLE_NAME        : Sheet1$
COLUMN_NAME       : Payer No
DATA_TYPE         : 8
TYPE_NAME         : NUMBER
COLUMN_SIZE       : 53
BUFFER_LENGTH     : 8
DECIMAL_DIGITS    :
NUM_PREC_RADIX    : 2
NULLABLE          : 1
REMARKS           :
COLUMN_DEF        :
SQL_DATA_TYPE     : 8
SQL_DATETIME_SUB  :
CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH :
ORDINAL_POSITION  : 1
IS_NULLABLE       : YES
ORDINAL           : 1



PS C:\working> $con.Close();$con.Dispose();remove-variable con,enu;[gc]::Collect()
PS C:\working>
```

huh, looks like I'm going to need to make some adjustments to `Get-ODBCSchema` so it'll work with this data source; namely: `TABLE_QUALIFIER` to  `TABLE_CAT`, `TABLE_OWNER` to `TABLE_SCHEM`, and adding support for the file name.

```
PS C:\working> function Get-ODBCSchema{
>>    param(
>>       [string]
>>       [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
>>       $DataSourceName
>>       ,[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$FullFileName
>>    )
>>    if(!(test-path $FullFileName -type leaf))                                                                         >>       {throw "Missing file: $FullFileName"}                                                                          >>    try{$dsn = get-odbcdsn $DataSourceName -ErrorAction Stop}catch {                                                  >>       throw $_.Exception                                                                                             >>    }                                                                                                                 >>    if($dsn.Platform -NotMatch ([IntPtr]::Size*8))
>>       {throw "You're currently in $([IntPtr]::Size*8)-Bit PowerShell, and the ODBC is only available in $($dsn.Platform)"}
>>
>>    $con = [System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection]::new()
>>    $con.ConnectionString = 'DSN={0};Dbq={1}' -f $DataSourceName,$FullFileName
>>    $con.open()
>>    write-host "Downloading Column Data from $DataSourceName, this may take some time"
>>    $columns = $con.GetSchema('Columns')
>>    write-host 'got it'
>>    $con.close();$con.dispose()
>>    $count = $columns.Rows.Count
>>    [int]$aPercent = $count / 100
>>
>>    $ret = @{}; $i = $j = 0
>>    $columns.Rows.GetEnumerator().foreach{
>>       $qual  = $_.TABLE_CAT.ToString()
>>       $owner = $_.TABLE_SCHEM.ToString()
>>       $tName = $_.TABLE_NAME.ToString()
>>       $cName = $_.COLUMN_NAME.ToString()
>>
>>       if($ret.Keys -NotContains $qual)
>>          {$ret.$qual = @{$owner = @{$tName = @{$cName = $_}}}}
>>       elseif($ret.$qual.Keys -NotContains $owner)
>>          {$ret.$qual.$owner = @{$tName = @{$cName = $_}}}
>>       elseif($ret.$qual.$owner.Keys -NotContains $tName)
>>          {$ret.$qual.$owner.$tName = @{$cName = $_}}
>>       else
>>          {$ret.$qual.$owner.$tName.$cName = $_}
>>       if(!($i++ % $aPercent)){
>>          write-progress -Activity 'Building Schema Table' -Status ('Added Column: {0:#,##0} of {1:#,##0}' -f $i,$count) -PercentComplete ($j++)
>>       }
>>    }
>>    write-progress -Activity 'Building Schema Table' -Completed
>>    if($ret.Keys.Count -eq 1 -And $ret.Keys[0].Length -eq 0)
>>       {$ret = $ret.Values[0]}
>>    return $ret
>> }
PS C:\working> $s = Get-ODBCSchema 'Excel Files' (ls .\Book1.xlsx).FullName
Downloading Column Data from Excel Files, this may take some time
got it
PS C:\working> $s

Name                           Value
----                           -----
C:\working\Book1.xlsx          {}


PS C:\working> $s.Values

Name                           Value
----                           -----
                               {Sheet3$, Sheet1$, Sheet2$, Sheet2$_xlnm#_FilterDatabase...}


PS C:\working> $s.Keys
C:\working\Book1.xlsx
PS C:\working> [string]$k1 = $s.keys[0]
PS C:\working> $s.$k1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
                               {Sheet3$, Sheet1$, Sheet2$, Sheet2$_xlnm#_FilterDatabase...}


PS C:\working> $s.$k1.values

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Sheet3$                        {F1}
Sheet1$                        {Due Date, Invoice No, REC_STAT2, Comp Invoice Date...}
Sheet2$                        {FileName, EqLoc City, Invoice No, Sub...}
Sheet2$_xlnm#_FilterDatabase   {FileName, EqLoc City, Invoice No, Sub...}
Sheet1$_xlnm#_FilterDatabase   {Due Date, Invoice No, REC_STAT2, Comp Invoice Date...}


PS C:\working> $s.$k1.values[0]

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Sheet3$                        {F1}
Sheet1$                        {Due Date, Invoice No, REC_STAT2, Comp Invoice Date...}
Sheet2$                        {FileName, EqLoc City, Invoice No, Sub...}
Sheet2$_xlnm#_FilterDatabase   {FileName, EqLoc City, Invoice No, Sub...}
Sheet1$_xlnm#_FilterDatabase   {Due Date, Invoice No, REC_STAT2, Comp Invoice Date...}


PS C:\working> $s.$k1 = $s.$k1.values[0]
PS C:\working> $s

Name                           Value
----                           -----
C:\working\Book1.xlsx          {System.Collections.Hashtable}


PS C:\working> $s.$k1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Sheet3$                        {F1}
Sheet1$                        {Due Date, Invoice No, REC_STAT2, Comp Invoice Date...}
Sheet2$                        {FileName, EqLoc City, Invoice No, Sub...}
Sheet2$_xlnm#_FilterDatabase   {FileName, EqLoc City, Invoice No, Sub...}
Sheet1$_xlnm#_FilterDatabase   {Due Date, Invoice No, REC_STAT2, Comp Invoice Date...}


PS C:\working> $s.$k1.'Sheet1$'

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Due Date                       System.Data.DataRow
Invoice No                     System.Data.DataRow
REC_STAT2                      System.Data.DataRow
Comp Invoice Date              System.Data.DataRow
Equip Loc Street 1             System.Data.DataRow
T...
```

so, I guess this is more or less working and the only thing left is to clean up the bit at the end of the function that collapses the null branch at the head to collapse the one at the first child instead

```
function Get-ODBCSchema{
   param(
      [string]
      [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
      $DataSourceName
      ,[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$FullFileName
   )
   if(!(test-path $FullFileName -type leaf))
      {throw "Missing file: $FullFileName"}
   try{$dsn = get-odbcdsn $DataSourceName -ErrorAction Stop}catch {
      throw $_.Exception
   }
   if($dsn.Platform -NotMatch ([IntPtr]::Size*8))
      {throw "You're currently in $([IntPtr]::Size*8)-Bit PowerShell, and the ODBC is only available in $($dsn.Platform)"}

   $con = [System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection]::new()
   $con.ConnectionString = 'DSN={0};Dbq={1}' -f $DataSourceName,$FullFileName
   $con.open()
   write-host "Downloading Column Data from $DataSourceName, this may take some time"
   $columns = $con.GetSchema('Columns')
   write-host 'got it'
   $con.close();$con.dispose()
   $count = $columns.Rows.Count
   [int]$aPercent = $count / 100

   $ret = @{}; $i = $j = 0
   $columns.Rows.GetEnumerator().foreach{
      $qual  = $_.TABLE_CAT.ToString()
      $owner = $_.TABLE_SCHEM.ToString()
      $tName = $_.TABLE_NAME.ToString()
      $cName = $_.COLUMN_NAME.ToString()

      if($ret.Keys -NotContains $qual)
         {$ret.$qual = @{$owner = @{$tName = @{$cName = $_}}}}
      elseif($ret.$qual.Keys -NotContains $owner)
         {$ret.$qual.$owner = @{$tName = @{$cName = $_}}}
      elseif($ret.$qual.$owner.Keys -NotContains $tName)
         {$ret.$qual.$owner.$tName = @{$cName = $_}}
      else
         {$ret.$qual.$owner.$tName.$cName = $_}
      if(!($i++ % $aPercent)){
         write-progress -Activity 'Building Schema Table' -Status ('Added Column: {0:#,##0} of {1:#,##0}' -f $i,$count) -PercentComplete ($j++)
      }
   }
   write-progress -Activity 'Building Schema Table' -Completed
   [string]$k1 = $ret.Keys[0]
   if($ret.$k1.Keys.Count -eq 1 -And $ret.$k1.Keys[0].Length -eq 0)
      {$ret.$k1 = $ret.$k1.Values[0]}
   return $ret
}
```

and now I should have a version that works with the `Excel Files` dsn

```
$schema = Get-ODBCSchema 'Excel Files' (ls .\Book1.xlsx).FullName
```

---

### Edit2: Do Something with it

since we've gone to all the trouble of exporting the schema, may as well make some tables with it...

```
PS C:\working> $WorkBook = ls .\Book1.xlsx
PS C:\working> $schema = Get-ODBCSchema 'Excel Files' $WorkBook.FullName
Downloading Column Data from Excel Files, this may take some time
got it
PS C:\working> function Get-TypeString{
>>    param(
>>        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$COLUMN_NAME
>>       ,[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]$TYPE_NAME
>>       ,$TabWidth = 30
>>    )process{
>>    $out = switch($TYPE_NAME){
>>     'VARCHAR' {"   ,{0,-$TabWidth} varchar(255)";break}
>>     'NUMBER'  {"   ,{0,-$TabWidth} decimal(18,5)";break}
>>     'DATETIME'{"   ,{0,-$TabWidth} datetime";break}
>>     default   {"   ,{0,-$TabWidth} varchar(255)";break}
>>    }
>>    $out -f "[$COLUMN_NAME]"
>> }}
PS C:\working> $DBSchema = 'GreenField.dbo.'
PS C:\working> $sql = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new(@"
>> /*
>> * Infrastructure as Code
>> * SQL Server - Data Description Language
>> * Auto Generated From:
>> *    $($WorkBook.FullName)
>> */
>> "@)
PS C:\working> [string]$wb = $schema.Keys[0]
PS C:\working> [string[]]$tables = $schema.$wb.Keys | sort-object
PS C:\working> $tables.foreach{
>>    $table  = $_
>>    if($schema.$wb.$table.Keys.Count -eq 0)
>>       {continue}
>>    $fields = $schema.$wb.$table.GetEnumerator() | sort-object -Property @{Expression={$_.Value.ORDINAL};Ascending=$true}
>>    if($fields.Count -eq 1)
>>       {$fields = @($fields)}
>>    $enu = $fields.GetEnumerator()
>>    $null = $enu.MoveNext()
>>    $null = $sql.Append("`r`n`r`n")
>>    $null = $sql.Append(((@'
>>       if OBJECT_ID('{0}[{1}]') is not null
>>          drop table {0}[{1}];
>>       create table {0}[{1}](
>> '@ -f $DBSchema,$table) -replace '(^|\n)\s{6}','$1'))
>>    $null = $sql.Append("`r`n")
>>    $null = $sql.Append((($enu.Current.Value|Get-TypeString) -replace '^(\s+),','$1 '))
>>    $enu.foreach{
>>       $null = $sql.Append("`r`n")
>>       $null = $sql.Append(($_.Value|Get-TypeString))
>>    }
>>    $null = $sql.Append("`r`n);")
>> }
PS C:\working> $SQLFile = '{0}-IaC-DDL.sqlserver.sql' -f $WorkBook.Name.Replace($WorkBook.Extension,'')
PS C:\working> new-item $SQLFile -Value $sql.ToString() -Force


    Directory: C:\working


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         1/13/2022   5:32 PM          14908 Book1-IaC-DDL.sqlserver.sql


PS C:\working> gc .\Book1-IaC-DDL.sqlserver.sql
/*
* Infrastructure as Code
* SQL Server - Data Description Language
* Auto Generated From:
*    C:\working\Book1.xlsx
*/

if OBJECT_ID('GreenField.dbo.[Sheet1$]') is not null
   drop table GreenField.dbo.[Sheet1$];
create table GreenField.dbo.[Sheet1$](
    [Payer No]                     decimal(18,5)
   ,[Composite Invoice]            decimal(18,5)
   ,[Comp Invoice Date]            datetime
...

if OBJECT_ID('GreenField.dbo.[Sheet3$]') is not null
   drop table GreenField.dbo.[Sheet3$];
create table GreenField.dbo.[Sheet3$](
    [F1]                           varchar(255)
);
PS C:\working>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!!!  I tried running the script in PS after I set the DataSourceName but I don't get any output.  I also tried saving the script and running by passing the DataSourceName but it just says it's running and gives me no output or feedback.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JWest if it's stuck between `Downloading...` and `got it`, then the issue could be the ConnectionString doesn't work for the data source(DS), or if the DS is something like a file which only allows one connection at a time you may need to close any open PowerShell's that attempted to connect but never disconnected; however in the latter case I would have expected `$con.open()` to throw an error. What does `get-odbcdsn` say the DriverName is?

Comment: @Gergor y I had to pass in uid and pwd in connection string.  Now I'm getting errors about table qualifier and schema....this is an old pervasive database which has neither of those.

Comment: @JWest I've added a walk through of my process to adapt the function to another DS with a different schema. My guess is that you'll be running into kinda the same issues I was and hopefully this will be able to guide you through how to adjust it to to meet your DS's object structure.

Comment: Yep I was able to make a lot of progress on my dataset.  I'll post that update once I finish.  Just trying to get it to return the column names in a list instead of an array and then I think I'll have it.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @JWest ok, but if the hierarchical format of the hash table tree isn't what you're looking for you could also just as easily return the `$columns` instead which is a `[System.Data.DataTable]`

Comment: Yep that worked perfectly!  The original script and the hash was also great, I just needed to get more information out of it so I went back and returned the [System.Data.DataTable] as well!

Comment: @JWest uh, edit 2? I guess if the data table works for you go with it, but all the data is in the tree. Also you might want to mark the question as answered if you've found this helpful